# Python, editing csv, writing issues

Tags: python, csv, editing

I've been trying to write a simple thing to manage projects. The thing I am stuck on is the editing function.

```
def edit_assignment():
check()
if os.path.exists(fdir):    
    list_assignment()
    file = open(fdir,'r+')
    list = file.readlines()
    line_edit = int(raw_input('line to edit: '))
    list[line_edit] = 'x'
    new_list = "\r\n".join(list)
    file.write(new_list)
    file.close()
else:
    print 'error'
```

That is the relevant portion.

When I run this, what happens is, instead of re writing the file, it sort of blends the two. I don't understand what I am doing incorrectly, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Never ever call a variable "list"

Comment: What means "blends the two"?

Comment: and yes: the write() appends the additional data to the end of the existing file. You can not update a file in-place.

Comment: Some I'm somewhat confused, how would I go about writing something to edit a certain line?

Comment: read in phase one and overwrite it in phase two

Comment: open the file for reading, close it, open the file for writing, close it.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
if os.path.exists(fdir):
    lines = open(fdir, "r").readlines()
    line_no = int(raw_input("line: "))
    lines[line_no] = "x"
    open(fdir, "w").write("".join(lines))
else:
    print "error"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening your file using 'r+' for reading and writing. After reading the existing file all further write operations will happen at the position of the file pointer - and this is the end of the file. This is why you are getting the detected behavior.

Options:

- open the file, read the lines, close the file, open the file for writing, write the lines, close the file

or

- set the file pointer back to position 0 of the file (start) using fp.seek(0)